# How can I get the value of data-id and post it into another page using jquery post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

Here is my code

```
<a href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view" data-id="<=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
```

I need to be able to get the value of data-id and post it into another page. How will I do it? Kinda new at this stuff. I tried using the code below but it does not work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.view', function() {

    var val = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.post('edit.php', {id: val}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: `data-id="<=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>"` - the `<=` you meant to use `<?=` - missing `?` for [**short tag**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) syntax. If short tags are not enabled, use `<?php echo`

Answer (score 1):

first of all correct this line with below, **because of `"<=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>"` will not print value**

```
<a href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view" data-id="<?=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view" data-id="<?php echo $row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
```

Comment: I see. I already replaced it with <?=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?> however it is still not posting to edit.php